# How to convert complicated string to array ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a string lets say:

```
str = "[[{/"a/":/"1/"},{/"b/":/"2/"},{/"c/":/"3/"}]]"
```

What I need is an array of hashes:

```
[[{/"a b/":/"1/"},{/"b c/":/"2/"},{/"c d/":/"3/"}]].
```

If I use split, then too it won't give desired solution. 
Please Help.

Comment: Do you mean "array of hashes"? `[[{/"a b/":/"1/"},{/"b c/":/"2/"},{/"c d/":/"3/"}]]` isn't a syntactically valid array of "dictionaries" or hashes.

Comment: My bad, I mean't array of hashes only.

Comment: It's still not syntactically valid.

Comment: Its a json and I need to iterate through each hash, thats why need it to be in a array format instead of string

Comment: @dips, maybe you means backslash \ instead of slash'/'?

Comment: Is that `"[[{/"a/":/"1/"},...]]"` or `"[[{\"a\":\"1\"},...]"`? If it's the latter, it's just JSON.

Comment: You should have confirmed `[[{/"a b/":/"1/"},{/"b c/":/"2/"},{/"c d/":/"3/"}]]` is a valid array before posting.  btw, once fixed, it's not an array of hashes, it's an array of an array of hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a JSON string, then all you need to do is `require "json"` and `arr = JSON.parse(str)`. In the below code I've corrected your string to be valid JSON:

```
require "json"

str = "[[{\"a b\":\"1\"},{\"b c\":\"2\"},{\"c d\":\"3\"}]]"
arr = JSON.parse(str)
# => [ [ { "a b" => "1" }, { "b c" => "2" }, { "c d" => "3" } ] ]
```

Note that your JSON consists of an array with a single element that is itself an array with three elements. To get just the "inner" array, do as you would with any array:

```
inner_arr = arr[0]
# => [ { "a b" => "1" }, { "b c" => "2" }, { "c d" => "3" } ]
```